# MySQL update a joined table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I want to update a table in a statement that has several joins.  While I know the order of joins doesn't really matter (unless you you are using optimizer hints) I ordered them a certain way to be most intuitive to read.  However, this results in the table I want to update not being the one I start with, and I am having trouble updating it.

A dummy example of what I'd like to do is something like:

```
UPDATE b
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b
   ON a.a_id = b.a_id
JOIN tableC c
   ON b.b_id = c.b_id
SET b.val = a.val+c.val
WHERE a.val > 10
    AND c.val > 10;
```

There are many posts about updating with joins here however they always have table being updated first.  I know this is possible in SQL Server and hopefully its possible in MySQL Too!

Comment: You need to put the `SET b.val = a.val+c.val` before `FROM ...`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/sql-server-update-from-select

Comment: This example has SET after the from, and that examples updates the first table in the join order.  I would like to update a table in the middle of the join order.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Even if it did you could just change the order of the joins (`tableB b JOIN tableA a ON a.a_id = b.a_id`).

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The multi-table UPDATE syntax in MySQL is different from Microsoft SQL Server.  You don't need to say which table(s) you're updating, that's implicit in your SET clause.

```
UPDATE tableA a
JOIN tableB b
   ON a.a_id = b.a_id
JOIN tableC c
   ON b.b_id = c.b_id
SET b.val = a.val+c.val
WHERE a.val > 10
    AND c.val > 10;
```

There is no FROM clause in MySQL's syntax.

UPDATE with JOIN is not standard SQL, and both MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server have implemented their own ideas as an extension to standard syntax.

Comment: ORDER BY and LIMIt not use in join's

Comment: @zloctb, yes, that's a good tip! For some reason, MySQL's multi-table UPDATE syntax does not support ORDER BY and LIMIT. Cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Comment: This was the only answer I came across in a lot of searching that gave a clear answer and explained how and why it is different from other SQL languages.

Answer (score 4):

You have the ordering of the statements wrong. You can read up on the syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) (I know, it's pretty hard to read.

```
UPDATE tableA a
  JOIN tableB b
    ON a.a_id = b.a_id
  JOIN tableC c
    ON b.b_id = c.b_id
   SET b.val = a.val+c.val
 WHERE a.val > 10
   AND c.val > 10;
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd8e97/1)

Comment: That syntax doesn't work. You'd have to delete the FROM part and move the SET part to after the JOINs.

Answer (score 3):

Another correct construction, which we can use in this situation:

```
UPDATE T1, T2,
[INNER JOIN | LEFT JOIN] T1 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1
SET T1.C2 = T2.C2, 
    T2.C3 = expr
WHERE condition
```

The above example is take from: [MySQL UPDATE JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/).

Reaching for the [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/) we will find such a description of [multiple-table UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
SET assignment_list
[WHERE where_condition]
```

> The *table_references* clause lists the tables involved in the `join`.

So *multiple-table MySQL's syntax* doesn't support `FROM`, `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clauses as opposed to *single-table syntax*.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidOliver, for fixing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) should give you the syntax that MySQL needs and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Join/JOINtwotablesinupdatecommand.htm) is an example. Why do you need to join the two tables? is it to limit the records updated? I am asking because you can also do something like the following:

```
update B set B.x=<value>
    where 
B.<value> is in(
    select A.y 
      from A left outer join B on A.<value>=B.<value>
)
```

Comment: That examples updates the first table in the join order.  I would like to update a table in the middle of the join order.

Comment: I know its been LONG, however, you could pick a column in any table. If you just have to update one table.