# Updating table value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables in Microsoft SQL Server. 2 tables “Claims” and “Claims_Details” are populated when we ingest claims from our EDI software.
Claims
[image]
Claims_Details

[image]
Once those two tables are populated, we want to populate the third table which is “Claims_Transmittal”.

I use insert into query to update fields from “claims” and “claims_details” table. I manage to populate the table. However, the problem is claim details has these columns that are “procedure_code” and “procedure_cost” and are in new row for each claim Id. For example, claim id 1 will have 1+ procedure code and each will have unique cost associated with it. These are important to calculate total cost.     For each batch there could be 1+ claims and each claims will have 1+ procedure code and procedure cost. I would like to update the claims transmittal where the claim number will have all these procedure code and procedure cost for each claim. Something Like this:

[image]
How do I do it? I can’t even think about where to begin?

```
INSERT To Claim_Transmittals
FROM Claims_Details
```

I wanted to update

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score -1):

Use [left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546152/how-to-update-a-row-based-a-joined-table-in-mariadb)
example:

```
UPDATE user_login a 
LEFT JOIN p_pegawai b
    ON a.id_pegawai = b.id
SET a.password = 'Keluarga1'  
WHERE b.NIP = '195812';
```

Comment: Thats not SQL Server syntax...

Comment: The OP tagged SQL Server as the relational database engine they are using. Your update statement is not valid on SQL Server - if you check the documentation I think you will find I know exactly what I am talking about. Different relational database engines have different statement syntax, you have clearly provided syntax for a different RDBMS.

Comment: based on your query:INSERT To Claim_Transmittals
FROM Claims_Details i showed you another query witch can update tables with data from other tables.