# SQL Update after Joining Two Tables -Not working

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have a update query

```
    update B set B.i_description='travncore testing',B.Tm_id=35 
from backlog B join backToSprint B1 on 
B.b_id=B1.fk_back_id where B1.s_id=18
```

when run this query i got an error like

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'from backlog B inner join backToSprint B1 on
> B.b_id=B1.fk_back_id where B2.s_id=' at line 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: MySQL relies on a specific syntax.

Comment: You need to remove `from` and your syntax is invalid

Comment: Hi. (Obviously:) This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below set should be afer join and before where clause

```
update backlog  B  
join backToSprint B1 on B.b_id=B1.fk_back_id 
set B.i_description='travncore testing',B.Tm_id=35
where B1.s_id=18
```

Answer (score 1):

The right grammer can be found at [mysql-update-a-joined-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331687/mysql-update-a-joined-table),so you can try with below

```
update backlog B
join backToSprint B1 on B.b_id=B1.fk_back_id
set B.i_description='travncore testing',B.Tm_id=35 
where B1.s_id=18
```