# MySQL: Adding column to existing table. Have the values ready, how do I enter them altogether?

Tags: mysql

I have table with data on old game characters. I'd like to add a gender column.
If I do

```
   ALTER TABLE characters
   ADD gender ENUM('m','f') AFTER char_name
```

then I get a column full of NULLs. How do I get the values in?
Using an INSERT statement tries to tag them all into new rows, instead of replacing the NULLs.
Using an UPDATE statement requires a new statement for every single entry.

Is there any way to just drop a "VALUES ('m'),('f'),('f'),('m'),('f') etc" into the ALTER statement or anything else and update them all efficiently?

Comment: After you add the column you need to update the table to populate the values.

Comment: With a new UPDATE statement for every single row?

Comment: I would suggest two updates, one for `m`, one for `f`, with the appropriate `where` criteria, or a single update using a *case expression* - all depending on your data.

Comment: If you have the values available together with the key of your table, you can use the `UPDATE JOIN` statement of mysql. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331687/mysql-update-a-joined-table on how to do this

Comment: Are the `id`s of the characters all consecutive? If so, a temporary table could be handy.

Comment: Where do you have all the values?

Comment: ids are consecutive, yes. I'll look into how temp tables and update/join can apply.
The values are just written out. I had an AI pull them and format them as a sequence of ('f'), etc hoping I could copy/paste them somehow

Comment: *"hoping I could copy/paste them somehow"* maybe if you have some sort of gui that supports this operation. But even if there is one, it will probably support only a limited number of rows for editing. (Like "edit top 200 rows in SSMS) But in the shell, there are only two options: 1) an update query for each row 2) UPDATE JOIN with another table that has the data ...

Comment: Created a temp table, UPDATE JOIN took a second to wrap my head around, but it worked great. Shocked there's no simple command to do this, it must not come up as often as I'd have thought. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to fill in specific values during ALTER TABLE. The value will be NULL or else a default value you define for the column.

You may find `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a convenient way to fill in the values.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE characters (
  id serial primary key,
  char_name TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO characters (char_name) VALUES
 ('Harry'), ('Ron'), ('Hermione');

SELECT * FROM characters;
+----+-----------+
| id | char_name |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Harry     |
|  2 | Ron       |
|  3 | Hermione  |
+----+-----------+
```

Now we add the gender column. It will add the new column with NULLs.

```
ALTER TABLE characters 
  ADD gender ENUM('m','f') AFTER char_name;

SELECT * FROM characters;

+----+-----------+--------+
| id | char_name | gender |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | Harry     | NULL   |
|  2 | Ron       | NULL   |
|  3 | Hermione  | NULL   |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

Now we update the rows:

```
INSERT INTO characters (id, char_name, gender) VALUES
  (1, '', 'm'), (2, '', 'm'), (3, '', 'f')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gender = VALUES(gender);
```

It looks strange to use `''` for the `char_name`, but it will be ignored anyway, because we don't set it in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause. The original `char_name` is preserved. Specifying the value in the `INSERT` is necessary only because the column is defined `NOT NULL` and has no `DEFAULT` value.

```
SELECT * FROM characters;

+----+-----------+--------+
| id | char_name | gender |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | Harry     | m      |
|  2 | Ron       | m      |
|  3 | Hermione  | f      |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gnRue2Bc)

Comment: That worked great. Even on a large dataset, if you have the values ready you can run them through a quick function or even have AI put the values into the right format. MySQL flagged that soon it won't work unless you give the values an alias and then replace "VALUES(gender)" with "alias.gender" in the final clause, but that was easy, too. May be a matter of taste between this and the UPDATE JOIN method.

Incidentally, this was an uncommonly relevant, clear, and thorough answer. Thank you!