# MySQL update via join - why is it slow?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE
    `temp_table`,
    `sms`
SET
    `sms`.`to` = `temp_table`.`new_value`
WHERE
    `sms`.`to` = `temp_table`.`old_value`;
```

`temp_table` has ~200,000 rows.

`sms` has ~2,000,000 rows.

`sms`.`to`, `temp_table`.`new_value`, and `temp_table`.`old_value` are VARCHAR(255) with indexes.

Values are UK phone numbers.

The update query is slow it never completes. Does anyone know why?

**Explain:**

[image: Result of EXPLAIN]

**Text Results for Creating Tables:**

*From phpMyAdmin*

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_table` (
    `old_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `new_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

ALTER TABLE `temp_table`
    ADD KEY `old_value` (`old_value`),
    ADD KEY `new_value` (`new_value`);

CREATE TABLE `sms` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `branch_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `message_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `message` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `from` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `to` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `sms`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ADD KEY `idx-sms-branch_id` (`branch_id`),
    ADD KEY `idx-sms-customer_id` (`customer_id`),
    ADD KEY `idx-sms-message_id` (`message_id`),
    ADD KEY `idx-sms-to` (`to`),
    ADD KEY `idx-sms-created_at` (`created_at`),
    ADD KEY `idx-sms-updated_at` (`updated_at`);

ALTER TABLE `sms`
    MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Please learn to use ANSI `JOIN` syntax instead of cross-products, it makes the queries easier to understand.

Comment: Have you tried using `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan?

Comment: your query will produce an error https://dbfiddle.uk/Pq3-7qfk

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE temp_table; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE sms; for analysis.

Comment: @Barmar Results of explain added.

Comment: @nbk Just a copy and paste oversight.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Create table SQL added.

Comment: Usually you have combined keys and nor one for every column, besides all keys need to be updated, that will cost also

Comment: @nbk a combined column index didn't make a difference.

Comment: @dai.hopPlease post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE temp_table; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE sms; for analysis - for an accurate picture of how your tables exist in their present form.  The structure could be much different than the pieces that someone planned to implement.

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @nbk - I don't see that changing the indexes on `sms` will matter for this query.  OTOH, changes to the temp _may_ help significantly.

Comment: Does anyone agree it is time to ask @dai.hop to start a NEW Question if he has not been successful by now?  So many suggestions and we can not get the RESULTS of SHOW CREATE TABLE (anything) posted to know what he is working with today.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MySQL Update with Join](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/) in your query.

```
UPDATE `sms`
JOIN `temp_table` ON `sms`.`to` = `temp_table`.`old_value`
SET `sms`.`to` = `temp_table`.`new_value`;
```

Also, it would be better if you can indexes the search column **"temp_table.old_value"**.

```
ALTER TABLE `temp_table` ADD INDEX `idx_old_value` (`old_value`);
```

So, search result be faster.

Comment: If I can give an answer, this is my suggestion. I have experienced the same thing, and when I change to this format, query went fast.

Answer (score 0):

- If the Optimizer chooses to walk through `sms` (and then `JOIN` to the other table), then it would be better for `temp_table` to have `INDEX(old_value, new_value)` _instead of `INDEX(old_value)`.
- Why are both `message_id` and the message text in this table?  Possibly having that pair in another table would make this query much faster.  (Then have only the `message_id` in this table.  This is especially important if the `text` is often quite large.
- `UPDATEing` 200K rows all at once takes much time and RAM.  One plan is to do the updates 1K at a time.  See [*chunking*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).

I can't predict which of these three suggestions will help the most.  I recommend doing all of the, if practical.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an [ON clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html), but you are using a WHERE clause:

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent **in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product** between the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table).

...

> The search_condition used with ON is any conditional expression **of the form** that can be used in a WHERE clause. Generally, the ON clause serves for conditions that specify **how to join tables**, and the WHERE clause restricts which rows to include in the result set.

In your case the end result **is the same** ([but in other cases is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)). Conceptually the "where" filtering happens after the tables have been joined in a Cartesian product, the query optimizer for sure can do something about it and "push down" the where predicate but I would suggest for starters to instruct MySQL with the [dedicated syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331882/11509101) to allow it to build an informed execution plan.

If you notice in the [documentation about update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) it says:

> The table_references clause lists the tables involved in the join. **Its syntax is described in Section 13.2.13.2, “JOIN Clause”**. Here is an example:

```
> UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price WHERE
> items.id=month.id;
```

> The preceding example shows an inner join that uses the comma
> operator, but multiple-table UPDATE statements can use any type of
> join permitted in SELECT statements, such as LEFT JOIN.

So the example used in MySQL docs uses one of the possible joins available and that one is the cartesian product

Answer (score 0):

The Explain of the Update statement shows the usage of 'old_value' (possible_keys) for the temp_table, and the select_type is 'UPDATE' for the sms table, both are different from the OP output. (see further below for my output).

Besides that there is also an inconsistency in the COLLATE and CHARSET definitions for the two tables, which could also have some sideeffects in performance.

```
describe UPDATE     `temp_table`,     `sms` SET     `sms`.`to` = `temp_table`.`new_value` WHERE     `sms`.`to` = `temp_table`.`old_value`;

+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                      | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | temp_table | NULL       | ALL  | old_value     | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                     | 21702 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | UPDATE      | sms        | NULL       | ref  | idx-sms-to    | idx-sms-to | 768     | sms.temp_table.old_value |     1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Testing with about 20k sms with 20k temp_table, my humble machine does it in 0.63seconds, where all records are updated. Note: only the relevant fields for the update query has been with unique values.

The Update:

```sql
UPDATE     `temp_table`,     `sms` SET     `sms`.`to` = `temp_table`.`new_value` WHERE     `sms`.`to` = `temp_table`.`old_value`;
Query OK, 20000 rows affected (0.68 sec)
Rows matched: 20000  Changed: 20000  Warnings: 0
```

Table temp_table:

```
describe temp_table;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| old_value | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| new_value | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

```sql
mysql  Ver 8.0.32
```

Good Luck